# Sorting in sql union

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, union

Suppose I have table 1 and table 2 with same column. I want to combine them and sort in order by column3 and column4, as well as preserved the table column order. How could it be done?

I got the following error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement
>   contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Query

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE 1
UNION COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE 2
ORDER BY COLUMN2, COLUMN3
```

Comment: There is a missing `SELECT` keyword in the second query of `UNION`

Comment: `select * from (SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE 1
UNION SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE 2)x
ORDER BY x.COLUMN2, x.COLUMN3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sub query
Example :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE1
UNION 
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE2
) ResultTABLE

ORDER BY ResultTABLE.COLUMN2, ResultTABLE.COLUMN3
```

This method can help you avoid ambiguous column and order your whole results.

Answer (score 0):

The `union` and `union all` operators work on complete queries. You are missing a `select` keyword after the `union`:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE1
UNION 
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE2
ORDER BY COLUMN2, COLUMN3
```

Comment: I guess that was just a typo, if select was missing error could have been:
Incorrect syntax near 'column name'

Answer (score 0):

When you use UNION or UNION ALL result set get the column names from the first query by default.  So make sure at the end of the query when you write ORDER BY you give the names from the first query(in your case table1).  I guess in your case table1 and table2 don't have same column.  So you need to write query1 (table1) column names in the ORDER BY.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE 1
UNION 
select COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 FROM TABLE 2
ORDER BY COLUMN2, COLUMN3 -- here column names should be from the table1
```